# Laravel 5.4 and React

Tags: reactjs, laravel

Does anyone knows if there is much difference in installing and using react inside of laravel 5.4 and laravel 5.6? I find alot of tutorial for 5.6 but the labs at my school only support 5.4 so changing version is not an option. Can someone tell me if it's pretty much the same or not the same at all?

Comment: There shouldn't be much of a difference between 5.4 and 5.5. I'd be more worried about a breaking change if there was a major update (like 4.x vs 5.x)

Could you just try installing React to see what happens? 

Also, Laravel comes installed with Vue. Have you considered using Vue instead of React?

Comment: I did considered it. Honestly, it's purely for the sake of getting to know React a little before I finish school next month. There is a huge demand for React where I am, and my school doesn't teach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much the same. The key thing is to know how laravel-mix works, laravel version does not matter too much.

Here is a good link for learning laravel-mix.
[link](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-laravel-mix)

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any different, react is a front end technology, so it runs in the browser, when laravel is a backend technology and runs on the server.

You may need different dependencies to compile the latest react version from the ones which comes with laravel 5.4. so run `npm update` before you start.